# Google API Events: update - how to update the event so that it is moved, not copied?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am new to programming and I ask for indulgence =)

I'm using PUT requests (as listed here [event.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) to update my events (there are a lot of them).

The problem is that those events that are already older than today's date (i.e. past events) are perfectly transferred by this method. They are created in the new given date, and the old one is deleted. Those. it seems to be transferred. But when the event is today or the future (they are all all-day), they seem to be copied, but not transferred. I tried the patch method, it selectively transfers, I did not understand the dependency. Is there any 100% method so that the event, regardless of its date (yesterday-today-tomorrow), is transferred and not copied?

In PUT or PATCH im using:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDARID]/events/[EVENTID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
"end": {},
"start": {},
"summary": ""
}
```

I tried to use the PATCH instead of the PUT as specified in the documentation, but it didn't help (partially helped, because some events were copied anyway and not transferred)
I tried to find the answer to my question here, but I didn't find it... my English is not good I apologize in advance

Comment: The documentaion stats the request is a PUT, you cant change it to Patch.

Comment: would you please  update your question with an example of the request you are sending then what it was updated to.

Comment: @DaImTo, Hi, I watched your videos on YouTube! This is what helped me develop my script to update the event. Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question about the request. I use the PUT query exactly as written in my question. Those. i send data only "end": {},
"start": {},
"summary": ""
Every time I request PUT, I'm authorized in (thanks to your videos) and Google allows me to edit my Calendar

Comment: I would like to test your question.  Can you post an example of the dates you are sending.  Then take a screen shot of what its inserting into calendar?  Or you could just show the response it should have the dates in there.   Im wondering if your having an issue with timezones.